# How to access Window.Service.Store namespace from window 8.1 app using WinJs

Tags: javascript, winjs

We have created a window 8.1 app using WinJs and distributed the app to our users. Every time we do some updates to our app, users have to manually update their app.

Now i want to enable auto updates to my app so that whenever there is a new version for app, app automatically updates itself (auto update).

i know we can do this by interacting with  Window.Service.Store name space.

[Download and Install Package Updates Using C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates#code-examples)

This code sample is for C#, but i need to interact with Window.Service.Store namespace using winjs.

Can anyone provide me code sample for performing the same thing using WinJs (JavaScript)?